# Remove column from QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I have `QTreeWidget` containing 5 columns. I want to remove column from the tree when user uses remove column menu. How can I remove column from the tree?

Comment: Hi ! Did you try `void QTreeWidget::removeItemWidget( QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)` ?

Comment: when it comes to 'complex' data manipulation - than just displaying - i prefer the model/view aspect because it gives you more controll of what is going on. sadly i never implemented something similar

Comment: @Zaiborg already i had reimplemented QTreeWidget as per your suggestion it will be difficult to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's purely for UI purposes you can hide the corresponding section in the `QHeaderView` used by your tree view:

```
treeview->header()->hideSection(4)
```

Comment: As i store data from column in XML file hide will not help me if you have any suggestion please help Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but the solution was rather simple.

```
QTreeWidget::setColumnCount( 0 );
```

They reload the headerLabels using

```
QTreeWidget::setHeaderLabels
```

This will make sure the the "removed" column is actually removed